# Proving a basis exists

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How would I show that there exists some set of open balls with rational radius and rational centre such that they are a subset of the reals.That is,

$\exists p,q\in \mathbb{Q} $ and $ r,x \in \mathbb{R}  $ such that $B_p(q) \subset B_r(x)$

It seems pretty trivial to me if I use the density of the rationals in the reals. But I honestly feel as if I'm missing something. I'm using the euclidean metric $d_E$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$

My attempt: Let $U\in O(d_E)$. This means that $\forall x\in U$ $\exists \epsilon_x >0$ s.t. $B_{\epsilon_x}(x) \subset U$. Because we know that $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ $\exists r\in \mathbb{Q} $ s.t $a<r<b$ then if we show that $\exists p_x > 0 $ s.t $B_{p_x}(q) \subset B_r(x)$

Comment: Density is what you use.  Can you list out your answer so that we can check to see if it is correct?

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: @Millardo: By the way if $q\in Q$ then we must be in $R$, right?

Comment: yes, I previously stated it in the question.

Comment: Are you trying to find a countable basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: no actually. I just want to prove that relation I stated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to show is

$$\forall r,x \in \mathbb{R} \quad \textrm{with}\quad r>0 \quad \exists p,q \in \mathbb{Q} \quad \textrm{with}\quad  p>0 \quad \textrm{such that} \quad B_p(q) \subset B_r(x).$$

Ineed, choose $q \in B_{r/2}(x) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $p \in (0,r/2) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ which exist by density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.